# How to overlay two gauge controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, gauge

I've set up binding of a double value to an `AngularBlockBar` control. There are two gauges in the layout, but the AngularBlockBar which is over layed on top of the AngularGauge doesn't show its binding value updating on screen, although valid binding values are being updated to it.

To debug this, I've checked first that the binding value that is bound to the AngularBlockBar is valid and this shows as true by setting a break point.

The binding value shows as valid.
[image: binding value]

I'm thinking its because of the way the two gauges are over layed over each other, which causes the AngularBlockBar's binding to not show.

Does anyone know what the issue could be here, that prevents the AngularblockBar's binding from being shown on screen?

The layout below is the main user control of the application where the two gauges are over layed. The first gauge updates correctly with a white fill value as shown in the screen shot below. But the AngularBlockBar which has a blue fill value isn't updated

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"   
             xmlns:gauges="http://gu.se/Gauges"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyoTestv4"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="MyoTestv4.AdductionAbductionFlexionView"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">


            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="statusTbx" Background="#141c28" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#141c28" Height="30" Margin="0,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CurrentStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="poseStatusTbx" Background="#141c28" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#141c28" Height="39" Margin="80,4,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PoseStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="degreeOfAbductionTbx" Background="#141c28" Foreground="White" Height="22" Margin="0,246,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DegreeStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47"/>
            <Label Content="Arc start:" Foreground="#00bdde" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/abduction_side_trans.png" x:Name="exerciseImage" Height="100" Margin="0,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="painfulArcEndTbx" Background="#141c28" Foreground="White" Height="22" Margin="62,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding EndDegreeStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48"/>
            <Label Content="Arc end:" Foreground="#00bdde" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,217,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="painfulArcStartTbx" Background="#141c28" Foreground="White" Height="23" Margin="62,189,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding StartDegreeStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48"/>


            <Grid>

                <gauges:AngularGauge
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         IsDirectionReversed="False"
                                         MajorTickFrequency="8"
                                         FontSize="10"
                                         MajorTicks="10"
                                         MaxAngle="0"
                                         Maximum="180"
                                         MinAngle="-180"
                                         Minimum="0"
                                         Style="{StaticResource FatAngular}"
                                         MinorTickFrequency="4"
                                         Value="{Binding DegreeStatus}" Margin="149,2,-89,2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
                                         >
                    <gauges:AngularGauge.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-89.642"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </gauges:AngularGauge.RenderTransform>

                </gauges:AngularGauge>

                <gauges:AngularBlockBar 
                        MaxAngle="180"
                        Maximum="1"
                        MinAngle="0"
                        Minimum="0"
                        Opacity="0.2"
                        ReservedSpace="50"
                        Margin="149,2,-96,0"
                        TickLength="55"
                        Fill="DodgerBlue"
                        Value="{Binding PainfulArcStatus}" 
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <gauges:AngularBlockBar.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90.711"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </gauges:AngularBlockBar.RenderTransform>
                </gauges:AngularBlockBar>


            </Grid>

            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="repCntTblk" Margin="80,43,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="38" Foreground="#00bdde" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34" Height="41"/>
            <Button Content="Submit" x:Name="submitBtn" Command="{Binding Path=DataSubmitCommand}" IsDefault="True" IsCancel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Background="#00bdde" Foreground="White" Margin="0,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.76,5.093"/>


        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

The first gauge binding being shown, but the over layed value for the block bar isn't shown.

[image: angular gauge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to define Grid.Column and/or Grid.Row on your guage and blockbar other wise they will just lay ontop of eachother?

example with Grid.ColumnDefinitions, you probably want RowDefinitions

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNavigationItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    </ComboBox>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedNavigationItem}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you give a code snippet explaining what you mean? I was under the impression the grid just needs to be defined and what ever controls needed place inside.

Comment: No the Grid control relies on Grid.Row and Grid.Column attached properties to present its content. If you want to use stacked placement use <StackPanel> if you want to define by Top/Bottom use Canvas. There's many other containers as well.

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason why the block bar isn't showing beneath the gauge? Will try this fix and see

Comment: I want to present the block bar over layed directly on top of the gauge, what kind of container/set up should be used for this? You

Comment: I would use a Canvas and set Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" on the gauge and then set Canvas.Top="<pixels where you want to lay the block bar>" Canvas.Left="" on the block bar, you might need to set Panel.ZIndex="0" on the gauge and Panel.ZIndex="1" on the block bar

Comment: Okay could you give an example of that set up? xaml isn't my strong point :)

Comment: @BrianJ I think the properties you're looking for are Top, Right and ZIndex. The above code will place the second control ontop of the first control 50px from the top and 50px to the right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71995/discussion-between-brian-j-and-jasonlind).

Comment: So I tried replacing that layout for my gauges with canvas, but I get the error, "Width and Height" must be non negative
hastebin.com/emupaduvur.xml
maybe I haven't implemented this correctly?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly set your Width and Height on your child controls because it won't cascade down from Grid in a Canvas.

Comment: I've decided to go with a grid as canvas isn't really applicable to this situation. Can you edit your answer to include only the grid solution and i'll accept.